# Why can't pass a manually created Pair to method without a slip?

Tags: raku

`:5hours` is a `Pair`, `hours => 5` is also a `Pair`:

```
> DateTime.now.truncated-to('day').later(:5hours)
2022-02-14T05:00:00+08:00
> :5hours.WHAT
(Pair)

> DateTime.now.truncated-to('day').later(hours => 5)
2022-02-14T05:00:00+08:00
> (hours => 5).WHAT
(Pair)
```

However, when I create a `Pair` manually, it doesn't match the signatures of `later`:

```
> DateTime.now.truncated-to('day').later(Pair.new('hours', 5))
Cannot resolve caller later(DateTime:D: Pair:D); none of these signatures match:
    (Dateish:D: *%unit --> Dateish:D)
    (Dateish:D: @pairs, *%_)
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

But use a vertical before the `Pair` parameter is ok:

```
> DateTime.now.truncated-to('day').later(|Pair.new('hours', 5))
2022-02-14T05:00:00+08:00
```

So what's the difference between `:5hours`, `Pair.new('hours', 5)` and `hours => 5`? Why can't pass a manually created `Pair` such as `Pair.new('hours', 5)` to `later` method?

Aren't the following two the same thing, right?

```
> :5hours === Pair.new('hours', 5) === hours => 5
True
> :5hours eqv Pair.new('hours', 5) eqv hours => 5
True

> my $pair1 = Pair.new('hours', 5); dd $pair1; # Pair $pair1 = :hours(5)
> my $pair2 = :5hours; dd $pair2;              # Pair $pair2 = :hours(5)
> my $pair3 = hours => 5; dd $pair3;           # Pair $pair3 = :hours(5)
> my $pair4 = 'hours' => 5; dd $pair4;         # Pair $pair4 = :hours(5)
```

Comment: `:5hours` is exactly the same as `hours => 5`. Simply different representations. Also: `:hours(5)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although `:5hours` and `hours => 5` and `:hours(5)` and `Pair.new(hours,5)` and `Pair.new(key => "hours", value => 5)` are all different ways to create a `Pair` object, only the *first three* **are syntactic sugar to indicate a named argument**.

When you pass `Pair.new("hours",5)` as an argument, it is considered to be a *Positional* argument.  Observe:

```
sub foo(*@_, *%_) {
    dd @_, %_
}

foo hours => 5;
# []
# {:hours(5)}

foo Pair.new("hours",5);
# [:hours(5)]
# {}
```

As to why this is this way?  Well, sometimes you want to pass a `Pair` as a positional argument.  If a `Pair` was always considered to be a named argument, you wouldn't be able to do so.

As to why `|Pair.new("hours",5)` works as a named argument?  The `|` in this context, flattens the given object (which is usually a `Capture` or a `Hash`/`Map`) into the arguments to the given subroutine.  The `Pair` in this case, is seen as a degenerate case of a `Map`: an immutable `Map` with a single key / value.  Observe:

```
foo |Pair.new("hours",5);
# []
# {:hours(5)}
```

Well, probably any `Associative` :-)

```
say Pair ~~ Associative;    # True
.say for (:5hours).keys;    # hours
.say for (:5hours).values;  # 5
```

Finally, the `|` in this context is technically **not** a `Slip`, but syntactic sugar to flatten the given value into the arguments of a call.

The syntax predates the concept of a [`Slip`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Slip) (which was introduced in 2015 during the Great List Refactor).  It was only very late in 2015 that `|` was OK'd by @Larry to also be used to indicate a `Slip`, as they **conceptually** do similar things.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!